# VueJS: Multiple components listening same event

Tags: vue.js

I have multiple components listening for the same event: Tabs are listening for events of its content.

So in every Tab I have a `bus.$on('content::event', () => {})`.

But my question is how to know which `Tab` component should act because of the event.

An option would be pass the `tab_id` in the event and then in the Tab check if tab_id is equal to its id but I don't like this approach, it seems to be an unnecessary check.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
created: function(){
  bus.$on('content::event', this.compareTabID)
},
methods: {
  compareTabID: function(tab_id){
    if (tab_id == this.id){%do something%}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen for an event on an active tab then you can find that tab using active class.

If this tab has active class then take action otherwise don't.

Using id is also not a bad practice since ids are always unique.

If this answer doesn't help then paste your more code to explain the situation.